¿Como realizo un salto de página en React PDF?
Todos los elementos se renderizan en la misma página, no logro hacer el salto de página, intenté utilizando wrap pero sigue sin funcionarme, solo me pasa con los componentes , probé con el  y ahí si funciona normalmente, intenté aplicando lo que sale en la documentación con respecto al page wrapping pero tampoco me funcionó, quizás esté haciendo algo mal, ayuda por favor.
const PDF = ({ dataItems, nombreReporte, optionSelected }) => {
    return (
        <Document>
            <Page wrap size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                <View wrap style={styles.cuerpo}>
                    {dataItems.map((itemGroup, groupIndex) => (
                        <View key={groupIndex}>
                            <View wrap={false} style={styles.table}>
                                <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                                    <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                        <Text style={styles.tableHeader}>Nro</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                        <Text style={styles.tableHeader}>DNI</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                        <Text style={styles.tableHeader}>Nombres</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                        <Text style={styles.tableHeader}>Apellidos</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                        <Text style={styles.tableHeader}>Monto</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                {itemGroup.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                                    <View style={styles.tableRow} key={itemIndex}>
                                        <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.nro}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.dni}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.nombres}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.apellidos}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.tableCol}>
                                            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.monto}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                ))}
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </Page>
        </Document>
    )
}

export default PDF

